# How to tell the lifetime relation between two memory objects?

Tags: rust

I have two complex objects that have some form of lifetime relation between each other. My goal is to remove this relation to have both objects completely independent.

Is there a quick way to tell what causes lifetime relations between objects?

Answer (score 1):

Very simple: one has a reference to the other.  Lifetimes don't really come into it (significantly) unless a reference is involved.  If they are, then their lifetimes are related.  They may be indirectly related if they both refer to the same 3rd object somehow, but that is probably not what you mean.

This is no different than in C/C++ where if you have an object with a pointer to another, that their lifetimes are related.  It's just that in Rust the compiler enforces that you do it right (unless you use `unsafe` which is called that for a reason).

Comment: OK I understand the relation is caused by a pointer/reference. But the problem is that it is not trivial to find where in these complex objects the reference is. The compiler seems to know but doesn't tell me.

Comment: Somebody else with more experience might know a way to tease that out of the compiler, but barring that, try looking to where it's initialized.  One object *has to be* passed into the other, so look there, and then trace down to figure out which member (or member-of-a-member) is holding onto a reference.  Look for lifetime annotations on struct members, as per [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-annotations-in-struct-definitions) - not all members will have one, but the reference (or the object with a ref inside) *must* have one.

Answer (score 1):

Use the borrow checker. Rust compiler has a borrow checker that compares scopes to determine whether all borrows are valid. It will show the lifetimes of other variables.

More info here:
https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html

Comment: Yeah the compiler has this information but in my case doesn't tell me where the reference is. I thought there maybe is a way to get this information from the compiler since it must be there.